# VSCode uses wrong resource (maven/java)

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

When I try to launch my spring-boot project from VSCode I get the following error:

```
    2020-05-07 08:24:13.297 ERROR 8100 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.<init>(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:644)

The following method did not exist:

    javax.annotation.Resource.lookup()Ljava/lang/String;

The method's class, javax.annotation.Resource, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/m64024/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar!/javax/annotation/Resource.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/m64024/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar!/javax/annotation/Resource.class
    jar:file:/C:/Users/m64024/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar!/javax/annotation/Resource.class
```

But using maven to launch the project works:

```
mvn exec:java
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>dk.nuuday.wonder</groupId>
    <artifactId>basket</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>basket</name>
    <description>Basket service for wpapi</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <swagger.doc>2.4.10</swagger.doc>
        <swagger.version>2.1.0</swagger.version>
        <springfox.version>2.9.2</springfox.version>
        <apache.cfx.version>3.3.4</apache.cfx.version>
        <modelmapper.version>2.3.5</modelmapper.version>
        <jackson.version>2.10.0</jackson.version>
        <wiremock.version>2.25.1</wiremock.version>
        <spring.wiremock>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.wiremock>
        <jodatime-version>2.7</jodatime-version>
        <gson-version>2.8.1</gson-version>
        <gson-fire-version>1.8.0</gson-fire-version>
        <generated-sources-path>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</generated-sources-path>
        <generated-sources-java-path>main/java</generated-sources-java-path>
        <ping-federate-security-library-version>2.5</ping-federate-security-library-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.doc}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-models -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>${modelmapper.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13-rc-2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-contract-wiremock -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-wiremock</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.wiremock}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>${wiremock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
            <version>${gson-fire-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dk.tdc.pdsm</groupId>
            <artifactId>ping-federate-security-library</artifactId>
            <version>${ping-federate-security-library-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://www.baeldung.com/orika-mapping -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
            <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger.doc}</version>

                <configuration>

                    <configOptions>
                        <sourceFolder>${generated-sources-java-path}</sourceFolder>
                        <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                        <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    </configOptions>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-basket</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/basketSpec.yml</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>

                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiClient.java,Authentication.java,OAuth.java,ApiKeyAuth.java,HttpBasicAuth.java,RFC3339DateFormat.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>

                            <modelPackage>dk.pdsm.model</modelPackage>
                            <apiPackage>dk.pdsm.handler</apiPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>dk.pdsm.handler</invokerPackage>
                        </configuration>

                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-mobile-basket</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/mobileBasketSpec.yml</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>

                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiClient.java,Authentication.java,OAuth.java,ApiKeyAuth.java,HttpBasicAuth.java,RFC3339DateFormat.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>

                            <modelPackage>dk.pdsm.model</modelPackage>
                            <apiPackage>dk.pdsm.mobile.handler</apiPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>dk.pdsm.mobile.handler</invokerPackage>
                        </configuration>

                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-product-basket</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/productBasketSpec.yml</inputSpec>
                            <language>java</language>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                            <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiClient.java,Authentication.java,OAuth.java,ApiKeyAuth.java,HttpBasicAuth.java,RFC3339DateFormat.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
                            <modelPackage>dk.pdsm.model</modelPackage>
                            <apiPackage>dk.pdsm.product.handler</apiPackage>
                            <invokerPackage>dk.pdsm.product.handler</invokerPackage>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>dk.nuuday.wonder.basket.BasketApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            swagger-codegen-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [2.4.10,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>generate</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>pdsm-yousee</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://private.dk/repository/yousee-maven-releases/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

launch.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "CodeLens (Launch) - BasketApplication",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "dk.nuuday.wonder.basket.BasketApplication",
            "projectName": "basket",
            "console": "internalConsole"
        }
    ]
}
```

settings.json

```
{
    "java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic"
}
```

Does anyone experince the same thing? I have tried a lot of different things, but can't seem to get it to work. Mostly different maven dependencies and excluding libs from dependencies.
But since *mvn exec:java* works and I can run the jar build with *mvn clean install* then I would expect VSCode to be able to run it aswell.